# How to calc the similarity of two images

Tags: python, distance, similarity, sift, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to examine two images for similarity with the usage of SIFT. The result should be a percentage.

I have understood how to extract the features and descriptors from the images using OpenCV an its lib. If I calculate the distance between the descriptors I don't get a percentage. I have not yet sorted my head correctly how to calculate this.

Can someone help me put the missing piece in my head together properly?

```
alg = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

trainFiles = getPaths(dirTrain)
images = []


for file in trainFiles:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    images.append(img)

np_images = np.array(images)
descriptors = np.zeros((1,128)) #Matrix to hold the descriptors

for i,img in enumerate(np_images):
    kp, des     = alg.detectAndCompute(img,None)
    descriptors = np.concatenate((descriptors,des),axis=0)
    print('Processed image {} of {}'.format(i,len(np_images)))

descriptors = descriptors[1:,:]

a = descriptors[0]
b = descriptors[1]
# euclidean distance 
dist = np.linalg.norm(a-b)
```

Comment: I do not really know about SIFT and distance between images, but to get a percentage you need to define a ratio. What images would have the maximum distance (100%) between each other? Could they be a full black image and a white black image? Once you have this distance, you have the denominator of your ratio and you can measure your distances with a percentage.